# Non-exhaustive patterns in function compress

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a function called `compress` such that if a list contains repeated elements they should be replaced with a single copy of the element. The order of the elements should not be changed. For example:

```
 λ> compress "aaaabccaadeeee"
```

```
"abcade"
```

I have two solutions, `compress` and `compress'`, that I thought are equivalent. However, `compress'` works while `compress` gives the error: "Non-exhaustive patters in function". I thought that `compress` will cover all cases, but I am not sure what went wrong. Thanks!

```
compress (x:ys@(y:_))
  | null (x:ys) = []
  | null ys = [x]
  | x /= y = x : compress ys
  | x == y = compress ys

λ\> compress "aaaabccaadeeee"
Non-exhaustive patterns in function compress

compress' (x:ys@(y:_))
  | x == y    = compress' ys
  | otherwise = x : compress' ys
compress' ys = ys

λ\> compress' "aaaabccaadeeee"
"abcade"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pattern has two `:`, meaning it only matches lists with 2 or more elements. You still need definitions for empty and singleton lists:

```
compress [] = ...
compress [x] = ...
```

The various guards are all only applied to lists matching the pattern used in the single definition you provide. (In particular, note that `null (x:ys)` will never be true; `null` only returns true on `[]`, not any list involving the `:` constructor.)

In `compress'`, the irrefutable pattern `y` matches any list not matched by pattern in the first definition.

Comment: Or if those patterns follow the one the OP has show, they need only be `compress x = x`

Comment: Originally, I didn't want to imply or hint that only one case was needed, but then I noticed `compress'`addressed that.

Answer (score 1):

As already specified in the answer, `null (x : ys)` can *never* be `True`, since we did already do pattern matching with `(x:ys@(y:_))`, we know the pattern will only "fire" in case the list has at least two elements. We then even construct a new list `(x : ys)` which means a list that has at least one element `x` followed by a (non-empty) list `ys`, so the `null` check is done on a list that has *at least* two elements.

We thus need to define different patterns for the empty and singleton list:

```
compress :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
compress [] = []
compress [x] = [x]
compress (x:ys@(y:_))
  | x /= y = x : compress ys
  | otherwise = compress ys
```

We can however boost efficiency and prevent unpacking each node of the list twice with a helper function:

```
compress :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
compress [] = []
compress (x:xs) = go xs x
  where go [] x = [x]
        go (x2:xs) x
            | x2 == x = go xs x
            | otherwise = x : go xs x2
```

Here we thus work with two parameters, and each node in the list is only unpacked once.